# Battery volt to 5 volt

Tags: voltage-regulator

I have two 3.7 volt batteries (I can use one or two) and I need 5 volts.
Initially I thought to use the lm7805 but the circuit absorbs 4 amprere.
how can I do? I need the component to be as small as possible.

Comment: A suitable buck converter. Go to TI webench and enter your parameters.

Comment: Hello, welcome to this community. I don't have time to write a full answer. But definitely it is possible. Could you please define better your requirement about the size ? If you says as small as possible we may suggest you some technologies very small but extremely difficult to employ using hobbyist equipment.

Comment: "mini360" buck module can do 3A but not full time.  4A needs the much larger XL4005 module

Answer (score -1):

go for a buck converter - if you plan to use 2 cells

go for a boost converter - if you plan to use single battery

use LM1084 which is 5V, 5A LDO voltage regulator. - which is highly not recommended, unless until you don't have possibility for above two options.

its better to go for the first two options.

Comment: at 15W you'll need a big heatsink.

Comment: Yeh, his power requirement is 20 Watt. he need to use bigger heat sink

Comment: at 15W / 5V = 3A and a dropout voltage of 2·3.7 V - 5 V = 2.4 V you most definitely would not need an LDO, and would also avoid using one for the heat sinking problems. That recommendation is a bad one. The buck and boost recommendations are right – why do you first recommend something sensible, and then recommend the opposite?

Comment: That's what I suggested ... for his single component option I had given alternative

Comment: thanks for the reply, The batteries will not be at 3.7v when their capacity is at 20 or 30 %.. so i suggested to use LDO while going with voltage regulator approach.. but its not recommended i updated in my answer.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Lithum cells are higly variable in voltage 4.2V  when fully charged and 3.0 when depleted, an LDO is a good idea if taking the linear approach.

Comment: @Jasen but taking the linear approach here for anything but extremely small currents is a bad choice <sup>TM</sup>.